# How to check if a text is contained into another?

Tags: php, text, levenshtein-distance

I'm developing a documents system that, each time that a new one is created, it has to detect and discard duplicates in a database of about 500.000 records.

For now, I'm using a search engine to retrieve the 20 most similar documents, and compare them with the new one that we're trying to create. The problem is that I have to check if the new document is similar (that's easy with similar_text), or even if it's contained inside the other text, all this operations considering that the text may have been partly changed by the user (here is the problem). How I can do that?

For example:

```
<?php

$new = "the wild lion";

$candidates = array(
  'the dangerous lion lives in Africa',//$new is contained into this one, but has changed 'wild' to 'dangerous', it has to be detected as duplicate
  'rhinoceros are native to Africa and three to southern Asia.'
);

foreach ( $candidates as $candidate ) {
  if( $candidate is similar or $new is contained in it) {
       //Duplicated!!
  }
}
```

Of course, in my system the documents are longer than 3 words :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the temporal solution I'm using:

```
function contained($text1, $text2, $factor = 0.9) {
    //Split into words
    $pattern= '/((^\p{P}+)|(\p{P}*\s+\p{P}*)|(\p{P}+$))/u';
    $words1 = preg_split($pattern, mb_strtolower($text1), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $words2 = preg_split($pattern, mb_strtolower($text2), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    //Set long and short text
    if (count($words1) > count($words2)) {
        $long = $words1;
        $short = $words2;
    } else {
        $long = $words2;
        $short = $words1;
    }

    //Count the number of words of the short text that also are in the long
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($short as $word) {
        if (in_array($word, $long)) {
            $count++;
        }
    }

    return ($count / count($short)) > $factor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few Ideas, that you could potentially undertake or investigate further are:

1. Indexing the documents and then searching for similar documents. So Open source Indexing/Search systems such as [Solr](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-apachesolr/), [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/about/) or [Zend Search Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html) could come in handy.
2. You could use the [sim hashing algorithm](http://matpalm.com/resemblance/simhash/) or [shingling](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/near-duplicates-and-shingling-1.html) . Briefly the simhash algorithm will let you compute similar hash values for similar documents. So you could then store this value against each document and check how similar various documents are.

Other algorithms that you may find helpful to get some ideas from are:

1 . [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

2 . [Bayesian filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering) - [SO Questions re Bayesian filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bayesian%20filtering). First link in this list item points to the Bayesian spam filtering article on Wiki, but this algorithm can be adapted to what you are trying to do.

Comment: My problem is not finding similar documents (I already use a index to search them), it's to check if a text is contained into another. These algorithms only work comparing one text to another, but not finding what text section is the most similar to the other text.